# How to pull data with a link on a different page with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I figured out the way to link to the page and set what ID i would like to call:

```
<a href="page.php?id=10">CLICK TEST</a> **(IS THIS RIGHT?)**
```

But then I need page.php to pull the id, this is what I am using at the moment to pull the id manually.  How would I make the following code pull it form the link?

```
<?php
$query = "select * from Drinklist where id = 10";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($Drinklist = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<head>";
        echo "<title>".$List['name']." - Site Name</title>";
}
?>
```

I tried the following (didn't work):

```
$query = "select * from List where id = . $id";
```

Seems like I can only find the way to do it with MYSQL and not MYSQLI...  Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
<?php
$query = "select * from Drinklist where id = ?";
$result = mysqli_prepare($conn,$query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'i', $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
while($Drinklist = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<head>";
        echo "<title>".$Drinklist['name']." - Mixed Drinks Station</title>";
}
?>
```

**Getting error:**

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given in public_html/page.com/test/inc/drink-page.php on line 6

Comment: So why you use `.` in a query?

Comment: Note get_result is `Available only with mysqlnd.` -http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php I tried posting earlier and deleting but mobile app failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up figuring this one out with a ton of trial and error...

Thank you chris85 for the early support and hopefully this can help you out a little. This is fun ;)

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "password";
$dbname = "database";

//Creating connection for mysqli

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

//Checking connection

if($conn->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$article_id = $_GET['id'];

if( ! is_numeric($article_id) )
  die("Looks like you are lost!  <a href='#'>Back to Home</a> ");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Whatever` WHERE `ID` =$article_id LIMIT 0 , 30";

$info = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($info, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    $name = $Whatever['name'];
    $description = $Whatever['description'];
    $keywords = $Whatever['keywords'];
    $lrgpic = $Whatever['lrgpic'];
    $vid = $Whatever['vid'];

    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $description = htmlspecialchars($row['description'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $keywords = htmlspecialchars($row['keywords'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $lrgpic = htmlspecialchars($row['lrgpic'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $vid = $row['vid']; //Use <-- to be able to have HTML in your database otherwise the above would remove <, >, /, ', ", ect. 

        echo "<head>";
        echo "<title>$name - Site title</title>";
        echo "<meta name='description' content='$description'>";
        echo "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords'>";
        include 'inc/head.php'; //includes already are in a php file ;)
        echo "</head>";
        echo "<body>";
        include 'inc/header.php';
        include 'inc/nav.php';
        echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
        echo "<div id='drink-name'>";
        echo "<h2>$name</h2>";
        echo "</div>";
        // AND SO ON
    }

?>
```